# Im trying to setup wampserver on a rdp to host a client manager

Tags: apache, wampserver

So im a dev for a GTA server, and im trying to use Wampserver on a Dedicated server, i have wamp all configured but when i go to the directory on the server it working for this sake lets say the ip is 144.144.144.1 so the directory is http://144.144.144.1:8081/manager/ which works on the actual server but when i go to that URL on my actual computer it says this. https://gyazo.com/2492ec034a9d97a11bd5663a0240b1a5

Comment: What version of WAMPServer?

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Host to contain your site?

Comment: Have you checked `httpd-vhosts.conf` file and changed `Require local` to `Require all Granted`?